# Good way to have ViewControllers accessing NavigationController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to iPhone programming and I am programming a app that has a NavigationBar on top, and several successive ViewControllers.

I was wondering: how should I design such a thing? Clearly the ViewControllers need to have access to the NavigationController, but how? I have created a UINavManagedViewController that stores a reference to the navigationcontroller, and all viewcontrollers derive from that class.

```
 @interface UINavManagedViewController : UIViewController {
     UIManagingNavigationController *navManager;
 }
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIManagingNavigationController *navManager;

 @end
```

However, since this is clearly a thing that all programmers encounter, I was wondering about the default way to handle such a setup. My beginner iPhone programming book didn't handle such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). All UIViewControllers already have a `navigationController` property which provides a reference to their parent navigation controller (if one exists).

Comment: And does the `navigationController` also have a builtin method that adds `self` to that property when a new view is pushed?

Comment: As it appears it's auto-added when you push a view to the controller. great!